# Java Abstract VS Interface in game?Which should I use?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

Which one is better when I want to create multiple NPC and items when I want them to perform some same actions,let say all NPC will move () ,checkCollide() while some have their own unique behaviors such as trade() , questGiving ()?
I'm currently using abstract since I'm not very familiar with how interface works and why they are more superior to the abstract class

Comment: Interfaces give you the most flexibility.

Comment: Interfaces are simpler, so if you can use a simpler construct, use it instead of a more complicated one. If you can't use an interface, use an abstract class, or class, annotation or enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces are better in many cases because a class can extend only one (and not more than one) class, but you can implement as many interfaces as you want. When you extend an abstract class, you have already an inheritance and that will make your class less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Donat's answer, interfaces also allow your classes to be more **decoupled** from each other, which normally means your code will be easier to be scaled. For instance, if you want to later add new types of NPCs, you can just increment new classes upon the *interface contract* or even create new interfaces. You can even start thinking about using Design Patterns, that involve taking this decisions, like the [Decorator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) design pattern.